# How to add alias name for a field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

My result is given below;

```
db.userdetail.find({}, {UserName: 1, _id:1}).pretty();
```

**Result:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("572981ddbe0da6156de04167"), 
    "UserName" : "anil"
}
```

Here how do I change `UserName` to `name` and `_id` to `value`, is it possible?

Comment: This Works Perfectly Fine:

db.userdetail.aggregate([{"$project":
         {
           "UserName":1,  
           "name": "$UserName"
           
         }}])

Answer (score -1):

You could use mongodb's [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), although I would not recommend it for big queries (you might hit memory limits) or very common queries (consumes more resources)